# SQL Query fine tuning

Tags: mysql

I'm working with this query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Categories 
  LEFT 
  JOIN Machinery_Categories 
    ON Categories.category_id = Machinery_Categories.m_category_id 
 ORDER 
    BY ordering ASC
```

I want to add in a WHERE to select by machinery_id, but when I do all of the categories disappear and it selects only the record.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Categories 
  LEFT 
  JOIN Machinery_Categories 
    ON Categories.category_id = Machinery_Categories.m_category_id 
 WHERE machinery_id = 5 
 ORDER 
    BY ordering ASC
```

```
Could someone explain to me how to select all of the categories but also only select the machine specified by WHERE machinery_id = 5.

Many thanks
```

Comment: share sample data and expected output.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Categories
 LEFT JOIN Machinery_Categories ON Categories.category_id = Machinery_Categories.m_category_id and machinery_id=5
 ORDER BY ordering ASC

but it is very hard to tell what you are looking for from the given inputs

Comment: That worked, many thanks, I didn't realise I could use AND like that.